# How to make axis/index visible always even if scrolled the page far right or far below in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, android, ios, visual-studio, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to make Xamarin forms application, in which the data should look like this.
[image]

However, it can be seen that the height and width of the view are large and I need to scroll the page both horizontally and vertically. So, when I scroll only the data portion should move while the A and B axes stay constant. If I move to column B6 then the view should be as shown below

[image]

and from this point if I move row A5 the view should be as shown below.
[image]

I'm quite new to xamarin forms or any other android development programming. At this point, I'm just trying to know what kind of search terms that I should use where I can find some documentation related to make such kind of view in my application. I guess a simple idea can be just using a scrollbar but I need my axes points visible all the time even if I scroll far right or far below.

Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To your question, you can search with scrollview, it is a layout that's capable of scrolling its content. You can set the orientation of your scrollview as "both" so it can scroll both horizontally and vertically.
But it can only have one content to scroll. It means  scrollView objects should not be nested with other controls that provide scrolling, such as CollectionView, ListView, and WebView. For more information, you can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/scrollview